# SingleVoucherReward' object is not callable"

Tags: python, django

I'm getting the error below when trying to save Campaign I think the issue is at  `bundle.obj.participant_reward(_SingleVoucherReward())` where I try to create and save a new resource before linked it.

**Error Message: SingleVoucherReward' object is not callable**

**Note:** the object `SingleVoucherReward` is saved to the DB successfully the error is on linking and saving it to `Campaign`.

```
def hydrate(self, bundle, request=None):
    """
    Tastypie uses a 'hydrate' cycle to take serializated data from the client
    and turn it into something the data model can use.
    """
    if bundle.data.get('SingleVouc'):
        _SingleVoucherReward = SingleVoucherReward(
            description = "test",
            subsequent_purchases = 1,
            auto_reward = 1

        )
        _SingleVoucherReward.save()

        bundle.obj.participant_reward(_SingleVoucherReward())

    return bundle
```

**Model:**

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, help_text="Give your campaign a name i.e Xmas Offer")
    participant_reward_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
                                                        editable=False,
                                                        related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_as_participant',
                                                        )
    participant_reward_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    participant_reward = generic.GenericForeignKey('participant_reward_content_type', 'participant_reward_object_id')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a model named `SingleVoucherReward`, then initialize an instance of `SingleVoucherReward` named `_SingleVoucherReward`, but your model does not define a `__call__` method, so you get this `not callable` error.

```
bundle.obj.participant_reward(_SingleVoucherReward())
```

It should be:

```
bundle.obj.participant_reward(_SingleVoucherReward)
```

By the way, naming `single_voucher_reward` is more explict for indicating that it's an instance.